How to disable row highlighting on iterm and oh-my-zsh?
I just setup the new Macbook today and start to have the weird highlighting with the blue frame on the row when i use my mouse to select a particular row on the terminal. The other row will be faded a little bit (please check out my screenshot for more detail). This highlighting only appear with the zsh shell (with oh-my-zsh). When i turn the shell to bash again, i dont see this strange thing happen. Also there is a small arrow at the beginning of each row. I tried to change every other themes of oh-my-zsh but the issues still happen. All the configuration of zsh is just the default settings. Does anyone know why ?

My zsh version is zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)
Edit: If I turn on tmux, thing becomes normal

hey. did you manage to fix that behavior? I'm having same problem.

This is iTerm2 feature added recently.
uncheck [ ] Click on a command selects to restrict Find and Filter
UPD: to get rid of tiny arrow at the beginning of the line
Go to iTerm2 preferences: Profiles -> Open Profiles -> Edit Profiles -> Select your profile -> Terminal ->
uncheck [ ] Show mark indicators



thank mate. it works

That's iTerm's Shell Integration (https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html)
If you want to disable it, you can do it by editing your ~/.zshrc file.
Look for a line that looks like this one and comment it out:
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" || true

Then, open a new pane or window and it should be gone.
